# Incrementing javascript problem

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm extremely new to javascript so I've no idea if I'm doing this correctly.

I've got some php that is filling a javascript variable array:

```
<?php

$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
$data = array();
foreach($pages as $post){
  setup_postdata($post);
  $fields = get_fields(); 
  $data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p>';
}
wp_reset_query();

// the js array
echo 'var marker_data = ["'.implode('","', $data).'"];';
?>
```

This then feeds this javascript:

```
infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]);
```

The problem is that it's not incrementing. If I change the "i" to "0" or "1" then it works. But obviously I need it to increment through.

Comment: and where's javascript ?"i see only one line

Comment: you have to use loop if want to iterate through JS array

Comment: Keep in mind they run on different levels. The JS runs after _all_ the PHP has executed. So if you expect them to work together, you'll have problems.

Comment: @SergeS It's being echoed out in the first code box, then the one line below.

Comment: Could you check to see what the JS you generate looks like? Also remember JSON is basicly javascript, you could consider using `json_encode` to echo your array.

Comment: @JohnP Is it possible to just increment through, changing it to 0 and 1 seems to work so just a case of incrementing.

Comment: And just to everyone, I'm at my limit with this so please go easy on me.

Comment: first of all - PHP part of javascript is only data - all i want to see is, where you are setting i and where you are incrementing, then it would be nice to know where you get setContent ( is this your function or framework or what ? )

Comment: @SergeS Here's the working example http://www.mediwales.com/mapping

Comment: Eh, as i see there , I cannot find the line you wrote above, nor the php script included - can you post it here ?

Comment: @SergeS Lines 90 and 122 if you look at the source

Comment: 1. now it is not working, 2. on line 90 is empty string now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment `i` in JavaScript, not in php, like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<?php
$pages =get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
$data = array();
foreach($pages as $post){
  setup_postdata($post);
  $fields = get_fields(); 
  $data[] = '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($fields->company_name).'</p>';
}
wp_reset_query();

echo 'var marker_data = ' . json_encode($data) . ';'; // Instead of implode
?>
for (var i = 0;i < marker_data.length;i++) {
    infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Rob Oops, didn't see that part. I also confused `data` and `marker_data` - sorry! Fixed in this new version. If it doesn't work, try two things: 1. Give us a link to a live example page 2. Go to your browser's developer tools or JavaScript console and look for any errors.

Comment: From looking at the source (line 90) it's showing the right data "var marker_data = ["<p>MediWales<\/p>","<p>Teamworks Design & Marketing<\/p>"];" (not sure what the extra slash in </p> has come from). So just a case of looping through that. At the moment it's only showing the "teamworks" name.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I may be misunderstanding something, but your example looks like it works exactly as intended: Upon clicking one of the marker, the HTML content is displayed. What is not working there?

Comment: @Rob Oh, I see. The inserted backslash is correct and does no harm. It looks like you're setting infowindow in an anonymous function that already gets `i`. Have you tried just `infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]);` (without the `for` loop)?

Comment: @Rob Your problem seems to be entirely unrelated to map_data; `i` is not set since it's referencing the outer namespace from a callback function.

Comment: Sorry what does that mean? Like I said, all very new to me so don't quite understand.

Comment: @Rob See http://phihag.de/2011/so/for-loop.html . If you're referring to a variable outside a function, you always get the "current" value *when the function is called*. Does the [linked demo](http://phihag.de/2011/so/for-loop.html) solve your problem?

Comment: @Rob For details on this exact problem, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example .

Comment: @Rob I added an anonymous function (`for (var i = 0; i < codesArray.length; i++) { 
 (function(i) { // ADD THIS`. Pressing `Ctrl+U` or selecting `View -> Source Code` shows you the source code.

Comment: Got it, just fixed it from your source. I can't say thanks enough, literally 10 or so people have attempted and failed. Thank you thank you thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Once your PHP runs and returns the page, have a look at the source and look at your JS. It should look something like this

```
var marker_data = ['<p>Comp 1</p>', '<p>Comp 2</p>', '<p>Comp 3</p>'];
```

This means you've built your array of strings. Now you'll need to use a javascript loop to iterate through it, something like this.

```
var length = marker_data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]);
}
```

Remember that all of this iteration should happen in your JS code and not your PHP code. They are not to be mixed like that.

Comment: Phihag has got the json working for the marker_data, it's just not doing the looping part.

Answer (score 0):

Good answears given above. This is a general old school instructional way how you mix php and javascript arrays, it can also be adjusted to your needs but I also suggest you go beyond it and look for new schoold things too.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRandoms = new Array();
<?php
$dbq="\"";
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
    echo 'myRandoms[',$i,']=',$dbq,rand(1,999),$dbq,';';
?>
var len=myRandoms.length;
var i;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    alert(myRandoms[i]);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```